# How to conditionally replace substrings in a text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
test_00000.png  0
test_00001.png  0
test_00002.png  0
test_00003.png  0
test_00004.png  0
test_00005.png  0
test_00006.png  0
test_00007.png  0
test_00008.png  0
test_00009.png  0
test_00010.png  0
```

My task is to replace all the label 0's(i.e., the 0's after test_xxxxx.png, NOT the 0's in the name of the images like test_00000.png) with 1's using Python. My code looks like this:

```
f1 = open('Text1.txt','r')
f2 = open('Text2.txt','w')
for line in f1:
    for char in line:
        if char==" 0 ":
            f2.write(' 1 ')
        else:
            f2.write(char)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

However, this code gives me exactly the same output as the original file. What did I do wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: The line does not end with a space.

Comment: Is the file separated by two spaces?

Comment: The original text file contains one .png each line. So each line looks like "test_xxxxx.png 0" and the pattern simply repeats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`re.sub`** with [**`0([\n$]|\Z)`**](https://regex101.com/r/TsUW5U/1):

**Regex Explanation**:

```
0                     # matches 0
(                     # matching group 1
  [\n$]               # matches newline or end of line
  |                   # OR
  \Z                  # Matches EOF
)                     # End of matching group 1
```

**`replace`** with `1\1` (replaces 1 with 0, and maintains proper EOL character)

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as outf:

  data = re.sub(r'0([\n$]|\Z)', r'1\1', f.read())
  outf.write(data)
```

> out.txt

```
test_00000.png  1
test_00001.png  1
test_00002.png  1
test_00003.png  1
test_00004.png  1
test_00005.png  1
test_00006.png  1
test_00007.png  1
test_00008.png  1
test_00009.png  1
test_00010.png  1
```

Comment: Just a followup question: can you explain what the \1 means in your code?@chrisz

Comment: In the regular expression, the matching group captures the particular line ending for each line in matching group 1. Using \1 in the substitution means that the proper line ending will be restored. So basically \1 refers to whatever was captured in matching group 1

Comment: If instead of replacing the 0's with 1's, I want to replace them with elements in an array like arr[i], what can I do? I use similar syntax except replacing " r'1\1' " with "arr[i]" in a for loop but get an error

Comment: You could replace with a lambda function. There are examples you could google.

Comment: If you give me a simple example I can update my answer later tonight

Comment: We can use the same example, but let's assume now I have an array arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and want to replace the 0's.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that just looking at the end of the line will be easier:

```
with open('file1', 'r') as f1, open('file2', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f1.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith(' 0'):
            line = line[:-2] + ' 1'
        f2.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Nope.  Not read only... The original value of `line` is immutable, the name itself, can be changed to point to something else.  This code is tested and works.

Comment: @SashaTsukanov, no need to apologize.  We are all here to learn and help.  Ask for clarification.  Either you learn something, or I learn something.  In both cases good things happen.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept that the output file can have 1 space you could use pandas to read it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
test_00000.png  0
test_00001.png  0
test_00002.png  0
test_00003.png  0
test_00004.png  0
test_00005.png  0
test_00006.png  0
test_00007.png  0
test_00008.png  0
test_00009.png  0
test_00010.png  0'''

file = pd.compat.StringIO(data) # replace with "path/to/file"

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', header=None).replace(0,1)
df.to_csv('out.csv', sep=' ', header=False, index=False)
```